# React js - how to reset react-phone-input-2 input after changing country code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i need to reset the input value after changing the country but it keeps the same value , i'am using react functional components , and i'am stuck at this point

this is my code below

```
<PhoneInput
         country={ip.toLocaleLowerCase()}
         value={phone}
         countryCodeEditable={false}
         specialLabel={""}
         enableSearch={true}
         masks={phoneFormat}
         searchPlaceholder={""}
         placeholder={t("register:phone")}
         inputStyle={{
           paddingTop: 26,
           paddingRight: 14,
           paddingBottom: 26,
           paddingLeft: 58,
           width: "100%",
           zIndex: 1,
           backgroundColor: "#F3F6F9",
           border: "none",
         }}
         onChange={(e) => {
           setPhone(e);
           setErrors({ ...errors, phone: false });
         }}
```

Thanks for answering

Comment: You can create a useEffect hook that will setInput(""), with country state as a dependency

Comment: defination of onChange is like this:  onChange={(phone, country) => {
          
        }}.
so you can set the initial value of country in state and whenever it changes you can simply reset your value of phone.

Answer (score 2):

Is `ip` stored in state somewhere? You might have a `const [ip, setip] = useState()` somewhere, and you then set ip in the change handler above to:

```
onChange={(e) => {
           setPhone(e);
           setErrors({ ...errors, phone: false });
           setIp(e.target.value)
         }}
```

Comment: Hello there , yes there is a setIp , i used it like you showed me , but it says it does not recognize value

Comment: Could you post the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this. It's working fine for me.

```
const CustomPhoneNumberInput = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState('');
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('us');
  const handleOnChange = (value, countryObj, e, formattedValue) => {
    if (country === countryObj?.name) {
      setNumber(formattedValue);
    } else {
      setNumber('');
      setCountry(countryObj?.countryCode);
    }
    console.log(value, countryObj, formattedValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <PhoneInput
        enableSearch
        countryCodeEditable={false}
        country={country}
        value={number}
        onChange={(value, countryObj, e, formattedValue) =>
          handleOnChange(value, countryObj, e, formattedValue)
        }
        specialLabel='Phone*'
      />
    </Box>
  );
};
```